# Where does the middle term go in Variance equation for continuous variables

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I want to get to the second line with only integral notations, without the knowledge of the $EX^2-(EX)^2$ formula

I do not know where does the term $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2x\mu_Xf_x =E[-2x]\mu_X$

It looks like it is zero, but I can't seem to get it aritmetically to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you expand your integrand in the first line you get the desired result.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2f(x)dx-2\mu_X\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx}_{=\mu_X}+\mu_X^2\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx}_{=1}=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

Comment: I see, looks like I forgot about the definition of $\mu$. Is the difference between $E[x]$ and $\mu$ only that in $\mu$ we use indefinite, whereas for expectation we use $\mathbb{R}$ for bounds.

Comment: @VLC :as usual, $\mu_X=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)dx$. In my answer I skipped the bounds for the sake of simplicity. Now amended, to be more clear

Comment: but isn't that also a result by LOTUS for $E[x]$

Comment: @VLC : yes of course. What I did is exactly an application of LOTUS

Comment: so $E[x] = \mu$  ?

Comment: @VLC : yes, exactly. $E[X]=\mu_X$